# python: shift and add unequal lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops

I searched a lot about my specific case but failed to get any solutions.

```
 A = [1,2,3,4,5............25,26]
 B = [2,2]
```

I need to shift B until a ends and add element to element. I wish to add these two list and store in C.

**NOTE** : Any value in result list which is greater than max value of A should start from 1.

```
 A = 1,2,3,4,5............24,25,26
 B = 2 ,2 ,2, 2 ,2........2, 2, 2 # shift B until A ends
     |  |  |  |  |........|  |  |
 -----------------------------------
     3,4,5,6,7............26, 1, 2 # if value exceedes the max value in A, it must start over
```

I want output as:

```
c = [3,4,5,6,............26,1,2]
```

How should i code to get this working?

Comment: when you say "shift" do you mean all the values in `B` repeat (`[2,3]` becomes 2, 3, 2, 3 ...) or just the last one (2, 3, 3, 3 ...)?

Comment: [2,3] becomes 2,3,2,3,2,3,.....so on

Comment: And when you say "it must start over" do you really mean A wraps when the sum is greater than the max in A? If so, the shorter code I've gone for really won't work and I think you should accept one of the other answers. However what happens when the sum is still greater after starting over?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*itertools.cycle*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create the cycle object of `B` and zip it with `A` and then loop over the pairs to calculate the sum of pairs under the condition :

```
>>> from itertools import cycel
>>> def adder(A,B):
...       m=max(A)
...       it=iter(A)
...       for i,j in zip(A,cycle(B)):
...          add=i+j
...          if add<=m:
...             yield add
...          else :
...             yield next(it)
...
```

Demo :

```
>>> A=range(16)
>>> B=[5,5]
>>> list(adder(A,B))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: how to handle wrap around?

Comment: @Explore_SDN: wrap around means?

Comment: If i need to make sure final list has no value greater than max value in A (here 50), how to do this?

Comment: @Explore_SDN So what you want to be happen if there was any value greater than that!

Comment: Lets take a new example now, if i have A = [1,2,3,4,........25,26] and i wish to add B = [1,1]. My result list should be = [2,3,5,.........26,1]. Any resulting value greater than 26 should wrap around and start over from beginning. How to do this?

Comment: @Explore_SDN: Check my answer. I think you want like this

Comment: @sakib: Not exactly. Can you please tell me with the latest explanation i gave here?

Comment: @Explore_SDN First of all add this explanation to your question and explain that *start over from beginning* from what??

Comment: @Explore_SDN: *start over from beginning from what* A or B?

Comment: @SakibAhammed: Start from beginning of A

Comment: @Explore_SDN: Okk just wait

Comment: @Explore_SDN: check the answer

Comment: Thank you! @sakib  You have helped me alot.!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that by [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
A = [10,20,30,40 ,50]
B = [1,2,3]
C = [ A[i]+B[i % len(B)]  for i in range(len(A))]
counter = 0
result = []
for i in C:
    if i > max(A):
        result.append(A[counter])
        counter += 1
    else:
        result.append(i)

print result
```

Output:

```
[11, 22, 33, 41, 10]
```

Comment: @Explore_SDN: check the answer. I think you find like this.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `cycle` to repeat the lists, `izip` to create lists of pairs, `islice` to generate up to the longest list, and `map(sum, ...)` to sum the pairs. It "wraps" to `1` (does not *"Start from beginning of A"* as in the comments) and because of this assumes zero will not appear in C.

```
A = range(1, 27)
B = [2, 2]
from itertools import cycle, izip, islice
C = map(sum, islice(izip(cycle(A), cycle(B)), max(len(A), len(B))))
# C is [3, 4, 5 ... 26, 27, 28]
C = [(x-1)%max(A)+1 for x in C] #assumes x cannot be zero given a wrap to 1
# C is [3, 4, 5 ... 26, 1, 2]
```

Comment: it's so much costly operation. you always doing *mod*

Comment: @SakibAhammed you yourself have a `%` n times too.

Comment: what will happen if i want to subtract the lists? with same conditions?

Comment: @Explore_SDN to subtract, you could replace `sum` with something like `lambda x: x[0] - x[1]` however you'd need to change `(x-1)%max(A)+1` to suit what you want to have happen. This should really be clarified in your question.